# Can Casl Prisma be written in vanilla Javascript or does it need Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma, casl

In the [CASL](https://github.com/stalniy/casl) [docs](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/intro) it states that...

> CASL has sophisticated support for TypeScript

[image: typscript snippet]

But you can use plain Javascript. I want to know if the same is true for the [@casl/prisma](https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-prisma) package. The example given seems to use Typescript (`type AppAbility`...)

[image: prisma typscript snippet]

And the docs say...

> TypeScript Support:
> The Package is written in TypeScript...

[image]

But that sounds like it has support for TypeScript but if you want you can use vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Hi, I don't have much experience with CASL but Prisma itself works just fine with javascript.

Comment: I was referring to a package that CASL made for prisma [@casl/prisma](https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-prisma) not Prisma itself.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can't really help there, sorry!

Comment: @shmuels, yes you can. All TypeScript code transpiles to JavaScript.

Comment: Did you or anyone find an example on how to setup prisma & casl in vanilla js?